# Magento - Redundant module

Tags: magento

I am currently investigating on magento modules. If the module don't have config.xml it will not work right?

The issue is that I have duplicate module:

```
app/code/local/[Folder-1]/Sales
app/code/local/[Folder-2]/Sales
```

The first module has no etc/config.xml

Is it okay to delete that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply delete the stuff. If it has no config.xml it has no controller, model, block, helper, sql script or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It is Okay to do that.  Make a Backup, Then delete it and find out if it works then ok if not copy again from backup.